# Script block js

Tags: javascript

For this script to work for me I need to block http://cursors.io/client_out.js
, any ideas?

> ```
> // ==UserScript==
> // @name         Prueba
> // @version      1
> // @author       wernser412
> // @match        *://cursors.io/*
> // @grant        none
> // @run-at       document-idle
> // @require      https://pastebin.com/raw/nptNsMQg
> // ==/UserScript==
> ```

Comment: While you *could* do this with a userscript, if you just want to block a particular resource, this would be more appropriate to do through the browser or through something like an adblocker